# Running javascript in a child theme. Works in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, javascript, child-theme

Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thornwalker/3LQjS/

I'm trying to get it to run on my wordpress blog and having no luck. My skill is novice at best, but up until now I've been able to muddle through.

This is the code I have in my functions.php (in my main theme, if I copy the functions.php to my child theme it won't run.)

```
function videoswitch() {
wp_enqueue_script('videoswitch', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/videoswitch.js',
array('jquery')
);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'videoswitch');
```

Finally, here's the videoswitch.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var directionsVar = '<video autoplay="" loop=""><source src="directionsVid.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>';

var storyVar = '<video autoplay="" loop=""><source src="storyVid.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>';

$("#directions").hover(function () {
$("#video-container").empty();
$("#video-container").append(directionsVar);
});

$("#story").click(function () {
$("#video-container").empty();
$("#video-container").append(storyVar);
});
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The script file itself gets loaded?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to check if it does.  I see an error in inspect element that looks like it's trying to load the javascript from the parent theme and the child theme URLs all combined.

Comment: `get_template_directory_uri()` always refers to the parent theme. Is this what you want?

Comment: Ah, no. videoswitch.js is in a subdirectory of the child theme. Should I be using get_stylesheet_uri() in that case? Since it's not a stylesheet I found that confusing.

Comment: Check the page source with Chrome Developer Tools/FireBug/etc. and look for the file or any 404s. And you should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It was indeed a directory issue caused by using get_template_directory_uri() .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to get URLs for the child theme.

`get_template_directory_uri()` always refers to the parent theme.

If there is no parent theme, both functions will return the same result.

Note that both functions do not add a trailing slash, you have to do that in your code.